# Error message on attempting to fit training data using GridSearch function

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, grid-search

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

polyreg = PolynomialFeatures(degree = 4)

param_grid = {'alpha': [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100]}

grid_search_polyreg = GridSearchCV(polyreg, param_grid, cv = 5)

grid_search_polyreg.fit(x_train, y_train)

grid_search_polyreg.score(x_test, y_test)

print("Best Parameters for polynomial regression: 
    {}".format(grid_search_polyreg.best_params_))

print("Best Score for polynomial regression: 
    {:.2f}".format(grid_search_polyreg.best_score_))
```

> TypeError: If no scoring is specified, the estimator passed should
>   have a 'score' method. The estimator PolynomialFeatures(degree=4,
>   include_bias=True, interaction_only=False) does not.

1)I understand that alpha is not a parameter for polynomial features. But when I tried to remove alpha and fit the data it did not work.

2) Does that mean that I am not supposed to use grid search for getting scores of KNN Regressor, Linear and kernel SVM?

I am new to python and any suggestion is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try `polyreg = PolynomialFeatures()` `param_grid = {'degree':[2,3,4,5]}`

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar Have tried that option. Gives me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

`sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures()` doesn't have a scoring function. It's not actually an estimator or machine learning model, it just transforms a matrix. You can have it as part of your pipeline and test its parameters, but you have to pass an actual estimator with a scoring function to `GridSearchCV`.

Fitting to data has a different meaning when your dealing with transformers vs estimators, only in the latter case does it mean `"train"`.